# Is it possible to install DotNet core CLI for dotnet core runtime?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, sdk, runtime

I want to run functional tests in a docker container.
Dotnet core **runtime doesn't have Dotnet CLI** installed which means I cannot call command '***dotnet tests'***.
I want to use a ***Dotnet core runtime*** image because it ***is way smaller***, the difference is almost 1GB.

Pay attention, I don't have an issue with building the tests dlls , I am doing build earlier in a different image and then put all tests DLL files to the runtime image. I want only run those test dlls.

The questions are:

1. Is it possible to install Dotnet Cli for .Net runtime?  I understand that there should be API and DLLs and classes that suppose to support cli commands. But maybe there is a way to include some part of CLI with required dlls.
2. Is there a way to configure .net core runtime to include extra classes/dlls (required to run Unit/Functional Test? (I have my functional tests written in Nunit that is why I am mentioning unit tests)

I cannot see anything useful on MS website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/.
Additionally, this message ""This article applies to: ✔️ .NET Core 1.x SDK ✔️ .NET Core 2.x SDK"" on the following page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21 about dotnet test command implies that the dotnet test command only accessible in Dotnet SDK .

Thank you for you time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't found the answer to my original question and I am still interested in the answer, I found a workaround solution on how to get rid of SDK and run Unit Tests of Functional Tests on .net core run time.

The following [blog](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/) helped me a lot, basically, it is the same solution.

Steps to run unit tests on .net runtime:

***The Plan, what we need to do***:
1. We need to get rid of the dependency on .net CLI (which depends on SDK).
2. In order to do that we convert our project Unit Test project to console application that allows running the tests on runtime in the following way.
3. Make Nunit compatible with command line run.

> dotnet FunctionalTest.dll.

***How to achieve that:***
1. Open your UnitTests.csproj file or FuncTests.csproj file. Add the following property to the property group.

```
<GenerateProgramFile> false </GenerateProgramFile>
```

So your resulting *.csproj file might look like that:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
     <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
     <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Nunit" Version="*" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2. Add the main method and Progam.cs into your project.

   class Program
      {
          public static int Main(string[] args)
          {
              return new AutoRun().Execute(args);
          }
      }
3. Open NuGet management tool in Visual Studio and install NUnitLite package.
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitLite/

***Now you are able to run your Functional tests on .net runtime with the command:***

> dotnet FunctionalTest.dll